# Conducting a hypothesis test for the difference of the means of two populations if the mean of one population is known, but its s.d is unknown?

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics

[image]

In the last part of this question,  I have to conduct a hypothesis test for the difference of means of the two plants.

H0 : uA - uB = 0 
H1 : uA - uB > 0

So I consider the sampling distributions of A and B. But I don't know the variance of B. How should I proceed? The official answer has just assumed this variance to be 0, but just because we don't know it doesn't mean we can take it as 0.. For one, a variance of 0 would mean that every single plant produces the same mass of potatoes in the case of B, which would nullify the significance of the 'on average'.

Comment: Add the self study tag.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that no, this can't be tested. However in this question, it looks like you're just supposed to take the stated mean of farmer B's plants as a fact.

Instead of the goal "Test whether Farmer A's plants produce more than Farmer B's plants," think of your goal as "Test whether Farmer A's plants produce more than the *stated* output of Farmer B's plants, 3.8 kg." This can be done without knowing anything else about the sampling distribution of B.

Comment: So we just consider farmer B's distribution as a 'constant' one with 0 variance and 3.8 mean? How would our procedure change if we were given the standard deviation?

Comment: Of course it can be tested!

Comment: @Saad if farmer B's distribution had a standard deviation, then we could apply a two-sample t-test to see whether the means differ. Instead, we apply the one-sample t-test to see whether farmer A's distribution differs from the stated mean.

Comment: @Glen_b My point was just that, as OP stated, just because we don't know the variance doesn't mean we can assume that it's zero. This assumption may or may not be justified; I didn't mean to suggest there's no possible way to test this

Answer (score 0):

If you know the population mean and you're trying to perform inference about the mean you don't need the population variance. It's just a one sample test against that known mean.